# How do I take my playlists from Banshee and put them on Itunes and my Ipod?

Tags: dual-boot, banshee, ipod, itunes

So I have a dualboot with Windows and keep all my music on a shared partition that neither OS's use. I want to know how I would import my Banshee onto Itunes. I also can't sink playlists with my Ipod from Banshee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sync your iPod in Ubuntu, use GTKpod. It is the definitive iTunes equivelent for Ubuntu. You can't import/export banshee playlists into iTunes on Windows. Welcome to the world of cross-compatibility. You can go through the hassle of making the playlists again, but it would take as much time to do so in GTKpod as in iTunes.

Comment: I assumed so for iTunes. which is a shame because I cant play my favorite tunes while in Windows, which is a lot because I do the majority of my schoolwork and other boring stuff on Windows

Comment: I agree, too bad. You can try to see if some of the programs you use work in Wine, a program that allows you to runs some Windows programs on Ubuntu. Unfortunately, Apple has a reputation for being very non-crosscompatible, so you can't import banshee playlists.